Calling `subprocess` in Python notebook has different `$PATH` than `!` shell
I am developing a wrapper class interactively in an IPython notebook.  This wrapper class invokes a command line program written in java, and thus I need access to the same version of the java runtime that was used to compile the program.
However, I noticed that using the convenient ! operator in notebooks, a different shell instance was being spawned than when using zsh in my terminal.  This was confirmed with:
!which java  # from within notebook cell
'/usr/bin/java' 

$ which java # on my zsh terminal
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java 

Running echo $PATH also yielded different paths for each.
I then came across this StackOverflow post, which explains that the subshell spawned by ! does not load my .zshrc file (which contains the modifications to the $PATH that are run when using zsh on the terminal).  However, the ! subshell does load the .zshenv file, if it exists, which I successfully created as a symlink:
ln -s ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv
After running this, ! now uses effectively the same zsh that I use on the terminal, and the commands work as expected with !which java yielding the correct result: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java'.
However, I was using the ! as a convenient way to test out and debug the shell commands; but ultimately, I moved these shell command invocations to a separate .py file where I am using the subprocess module.
Everything works as expected when I run the script from the terminal with python3 script.py; but when importing a function from script.py into the notebook, it yields the same issue as before.
As a minimal example, from within the notebook:
!which java 
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java 

This is the correct path.  However,
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run("which java", shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip()
output

Gives me:
'/usr/bin/java'

Why is the shell spawned by ! able to access the same zsh on my system as the terminal, but the shell spawned by subprocess unable to?

The underlying problem is that you're setting PATH in per-shell-instance scripts, rather than setting it in login scripts.

Assuming that PATH is an environment variable (which usually is the case, but better check this), the subprocess of your notebook inherits the PATH from the PATH defined inside the notebook, which in turn inherits the PATH from its parent process. Of course a process is free to fiddle with its PATH, but first of all I would debug the inheritance chain. Hence first you check the PATH at the point where the notebook is started (which you don't show in your questioN).

When you use subprocess.run (or related functions) with shell=True, it is explicitly using /bin/sh. It does not use your shell, and it will not read your zsh initialization files. You have to assume that /bin/sh is a generic Bourne-compatible shell
Running your script like this works...
python script.py

...because the script inherits the value of $PATH from your shell. You can always explicitly call zsh; instead of:
process = subprocess.run("which java", shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

You can run:
process = subprocess.run(["zsh", "-c", "which java", check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Alternately, if you script requires specific directories in $PATH to work, set that up explicitly by setting os.environ['PATH'] before calling subprocess.run.

Even though which is run via Bourne shell, this would not change the PATH, since a plain sh would not run any dotfiles which possibly could modify the PATH. Your solution OTOH, would make zsh process the zshenv files (in /etc and in ~), and they possibly could influence the PATH.

I think you're just re-stating what I already said in my answer: because subprocess.run uses /bin/sh, it won't run the op's zsh dotfiles, so it won't update the path.

I see it the other way round: It would be a bad idea if the shell being run would automatically update the path. If the notebook is already called with the correct PATH, any PATH change afterwards would at best not harm, at worst be contraproductive. This is also what I expressed in my comment to the question. The OP doesn't seem to react to the comments, it seems.
